# unclear error messages while testing an Azure REST API

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2015, azure-mobile-services, postman

I'm trying to utilize an Azure Mobile Service in my UWP project, though I'm having some difficulties. I tried to go immediatly for a live database on Azure, but when I try to test the methods, I get unclear exceptions.

I tried testing the API calls with Postman, using the following **GET** url: `https://wp-travelapp-g6.azure-mobile.net/tables/todoitem`

```
message: an error has occured.
```

When I try to run my Visual Studio solution, I execute the following line of code:

```
ObservableCollection<ToDoItem> ToDoItems = await todoTable.ToCollectionAsync();
```

and I get this error:

```
Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServictInstance : 
               {"The request could not be completed. (Internal Server Error)"}
InnerException : null
```

I noticed this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28653553/4658996). It says to add the role of db_owner to the right user, but I don't know how to do this.

I also checked the log entries for the mobile services and saw this recurring error:

```
Exception=System.InvalidOperationException: Database initialization failed. 
            Could not initialize one or more objects in schema 'WP_TravelApp_G6'. 
            Please ensure that the database connection string is correct.
```

The entire Visual Studio project was downloaded from Azure's get-started page, so I doubt any of the keys are incorrect.

*EDIT*: added more details. Changed nameOfMobileService to the actual name. Below is a screenshot of used Azure items. Like I said, I used the starter project Azure gave me, so I'm not sure what I should have changed.

[Azure structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yGbXM.png)

Comment: According to you error message, there may be no table named `nameOfMobileServic` in your SQLiteService, so you should create one in your Service. If you have done it, but this error occured still, could you please post your code?

Comment: I changed the 'nameOfMobileServic' to the actual name and added my Azure items structure in it. Your suggestion seems unlikely though, I use **ToDoItem** as a table, not 'nameOfMobileServic' as the table. Also which code exactly would you like to see? The DbContext?

Comment: This error message is so strange. From your Azure structure, i see `WP_TravelApp_G6` is a mobile service, and there are two Database, and `https://wp-travelapp-g6.azure-mobile.net/tables/todoitem` this means you get the table named `todoitem` in the database from this mobile service. Could you please double check that you connected a database to your mobileservice when you created this `WP_TravelApp_G6` service? This `todoitem` table should be in the connected database. And is there any custom modification in your 'DbContext' code? If yes, you can post it.

Comment: The WP_TravelApp_G6 service indeed has a DB added to it, as seen [here](http://i.imgur.com/zW0QHp1.png) As for the DbContext. I changed nothing, except for adding 3 other `DbSets`, Models and Controllers included of course. In the meantime I've tried redoing the whole thing with a different Mobile Service + DB, in case Azure is being a dumbass, will update if I got something worth sharing

Answer (score 0):

When I hit the endpoint with Postman, I get 401 Unauthorized, so I can't test much further.  However, I've created a UWP application with Azure App Service Mobile Apps.

Link to my repository: https://github.com/adrianhall/quickstarts

You can use a Node.js or an ASP.NET version of the project.  Just walk through the quickstart process on Azure App Service Mobile Apps and download the appropriate project.